# Running aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $test_env_variable --query "SecretString" throws error. what I am doing wrong here

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-secrets-manager

when I run the following aws cli command and pass environment variable as --secret-id. aws cli throws the error. however when i pass the hardcoded value instead of environment variable, it start working just fine.

aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $test_env_variable --query "SecretString"

**ERROR:**

usage: aws [options]   [ ...] [parameters]
To see help text, you can run:

aws help
aws  help
aws   help

aws.exe: error: argument --secret-id: expected one argument

Answer (score 1):

This happens, because your `test_env_variable` is most likely **empty**. Thus you have to ensure that it actually has secret id in the correct format.